# R - How to filter out duplicate data that has a unique identifier?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that is survey data. If i use distinct(x) the code will not read any duplicates as I have a "Survey ID" column that will always be different.

```
x <- data.frame("Survey ID" = 1001:1008,
                "First Initial" = c("M","P","S","B","H", "P", "L", "A"),
                "Last Initial" = c("S","J", "A", "P", "Q", "J", "P", "C"),
                "Age" = c(34,41,52,61,25,41,19,58),
                "Gender" = c("M", "M", "M", "F","M","M","F","M"),
                "Ethnicity" = c(2,2,1,1,3,2,1,4),
                "Veteran Status" = c("A","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","N")
                )
```

I can use

```
y <- distinct(x[,-1])
```

and it filters out the Survey Id but i need the Survey ID in my new dataset. How can i remove duplicates but keep the survey ID of one of the duplicated rows?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `distinct_at`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    distinct_at(-1, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

If we want to specify the column names

```
x %>%
  distinct_at(vars(Age, Gender), .keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is `unique` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(x), by = names(x)[-1])
```

Comment: This is perfect! What if i wanted to filter through certain columns only? Like in my dataset x, columns "Age", and "Gender"?

Comment: Thanks this is great! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do for all columns except the first:

```
x[!duplicated(x[,-1]),]
```

or for selected columns:

```
x[!duplicated(x[,c("Age","Gender"),])
```

Both will retain the first of the duplicated rows.